# Rspec stub method calls on records

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, testing, rspec, tdd

My test case is below:

```
    petition1 = Petition.create
    petition2 = Petition.create

    petition1.should_receive(:test_method).with(7).and_return(50.0)
    petition2.should_receive(:test_method).with(7).and_return(25.0)

    petition1.test_method(7) # => 50.0
    Petition.first.test_method(7) # => 0.0

    petition2.test_method(7) # => 25.0
    Petition.last.test_method(7) # => 0.0
```

How can I stub method calls for records retrieved directly from the database?

I am iterating over records in my unit test and I need method calls on certain records to return specific responses.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that (as you discovered) calling a find method will create a new instance of `Petition`. To get around this, you can stub the find methods themselves and just return the objects you want:

```
let(:petition1) { Petition.create }
let(:petition2) { Petition.create }

it "does what I want" do
  Petition.stub(:first) { petition1 }
  Petition.stub(:last) { petition2 }
  petition1.should_receive(:test_method).with(7).and_return(50.0)
  petition2.should_receive(:test_method).with(7).and_return(25.0)
  # test code
end
```

Unfortunately this couples the spec with the implementation of whatever method you are testing. If you use another way of getting the petitions, this may break. A more resilient approach might use factories instead, and create Petitions with the appropriate attributes.